# React three fiber raycast on texture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to upgrade this example https://codesandbox.io/s/text3d-alignment-forked-88mttv, currently i can move, scale and rotate the texture it's using useControls from `leva` but i want to make the texture draggable directly on the 3d object, how can i do that?

```js
export const App = () => (
  <Canvas shadows orthographic camera={{ position: [-50, 50, 100], zoom: 140 }}>
    <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
    <directionalLight intensity={0.5} position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <Cup scale={2} position={[0, -1, 0]} />
    <AccumulativeShadows temporal frames={100} alphaTest={0.95} opacity={1} scale={25} position={[0, -1, 0]}>
      <RandomizedLight amount={8} radius={10} ambient={0.7} intensity={1} position={[10, 10, -5]} bias={0.01} size={10} />
    </AccumulativeShadows>
    <OrbitControls />
  </Canvas>
)

function Cup(props) {
  const { debug, image, x, y, rotation, scale } = useControls({
    debug: true,
    image: { image: '/1200px-Starbucks_Logo_ab_2011.svg.png' },
    x: { value: 0, min: -1, max: 1 },
    y: { value: 0, min: -1, max: 1 },
    rotation: { value: 0, min: 0, max: Math.PI * 2 },
    scale: { value: 1, min: 0, max: 2 }
  })
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/coffee-transformed.glb')
  const texture = useTexture(image)
  return (
    <mesh castShadow geometry={nodes.coffee_cup_top_16oz.geometry} material={materials['13 - Default']} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <Decal debug={debug} position={[0 + x, 0.75 + y, 0.3]} rotation={[0, 0, rotation]} scale={[0.52 * scale, 0.6 * scale, 0.6 * scale]} map={texture} />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, sadly there would be no easy way, normally that would be done by finding point you click on uv of the object, and then you calculate the acceleration between previous click and current but in uv space. But the problem with this approach that you can get that info inside the shader, and to get this data on CPU you would need a readback, that likely not available on OpenGL ES

Comment: However there is way to mimic that effect for instance for cylinder, from knowing the 3d point on cylinder you can calculate the direction from witch you have to project uv coords for decal